# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'type.parameters')

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, ionic2, angularfire

I'm following this tutorial : https://javebratt.com/angularfire2-email-auth/  and I get a weird error.

I'm at the login page implementation, and I have already implemented these two files

login.ts

```
import {
  NavController,
  LoadingController,
  AlertController
} from 'ionic-angular';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { AuthData } from '../../providers/auth-data';

import { Page1 } from '../../pages/page1/page1';
import { SignupPage } from '../../pages/signup/signup';
import { ResetPasswordPage } from '../../pages/reset-password/reset-password';

import { EmailValidator } from '../../validators/email';


/*
  Generated class for the Login page.

  See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
  Ionic pages and navigation.
*/
@Component({
  selector: 'page-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.html'
})
export class LoginPage {
  public loginForm: any;
  emailChanged: boolean = false;
  passwordChanged: boolean = false;
  submitAttempt: boolean = false;
  public loading: any;

  constructor(public nav: NavController, public authData: AuthData,
public formBuilder: FormBuilder, public alertCtrl: AlertController,
public loadingCtrl: LoadingController) {
    this.loginForm = formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, 
        EmailValidator.isValid])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.minLength(6), 
      Validators.required])]
    });
  }


  goToResetPassword(){
    this.nav.push(ResetPasswordPage);
  }

  createAccount(){
    this.nav.push(SignupPage);
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('Hello LoginPage Page');
  }

  elementChanged(input){
    let field = input.inputControl.name;
    this[field + "Changed"] = true;
  }

  loginUser(){
      this.submitAttempt = true;

      if (!this.loginForm.valid){
        console.log(this.loginForm.value);
      } else {
        this.authData.loginUser(this.loginForm.value.email, 
          this.loginForm.value.password).then( authData => {
            this.nav.setRoot(Page1);
      }, error => {
        this.loading.dismiss().then( () => {
          let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            message: error.message,
            buttons: [
            {
              text: "Ok",
              role: 'cancel'
            }
            ]
          });
        alert.present();
        });
      });

      this.loading = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        dismissOnPageChange: true,
      });
      this.loading.present();
      }
  }

}
```

and auth-data.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2';


@Injectable()
export class AuthData {
  fireAuth: any;
  constructor(public af:AngularFire) {
    console.log('Hello AuthData Provider');
    af.auth.subscribe(user => {
        if(user){
            this.fireAuth = user.auth;
            console.log(user);
        }
    })
  }
  loginUser(newEmail: string, newPassword: string): any {
    return this.af.auth.login({ email: newEmail, password: newPassword });
  }

  resetPassword(email: string): any {
    return firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
  }

  logoutUser(): any {
    return this.af.auth.logout();
  }

  signupUser(newEmail: string, newPassword: string): any {
    return this.af.auth.createUser({ email: newEmail, password: newPassword });
  }
}
```

But when I do 'ionic serve' I get the following weird error about by login.ts

> Property 'loginUser' does not exist on type 'AuthData'

This loginUser function is here in my auth-data.ts , so I don't understand what it means .

My guess would have been that 'this.authData' is never initiated, but even when I add `this.authData = authData` in the constructor, it does not change anything. (that also says that I don't understand how it gets initiated)

Does anyone know why I get this loginUser error ?

Thanks a lot

EDIT:

Thanks to one of your advice below it seems like the error has disappeared and a new one is here (even if to be honest now even if I revert my change I still get the new error, I'm so confused)

Now the error I get in Safari is TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'type.parameters') and in Firefox : TypeError: type is undefined[En savoir plus]

Firefox console gives me

> ReflectionCapabilitieshttp://localhost:8100/build/main.js:45824:1
>     Reflectorhttp://localhost:8100/build/main.js:45964:16
>     CompileMetadataResolverhttp://localhost:8100/build/main.js:25506:38
>     CompileMetadataResolverhttp://localhost:8100/build/main.js:25471:21
>     CompileMetadataResolverhttp://localhost:8100/build/main.js:25357:51  map self-hosted
>     CompileMetadataResolverhttp://localhost:8100/build/main.js:25356:65
>     RuntimeCompilerhttp://localhost:8100/build/main.js:40363:24
>     RuntimeCompilercompileModuleAndComponents
>   http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:40301:32
>     RuntimeCompilerhttp://localhost:8100/build/main.js:40292:16
>     PlatformRefbootstrapModuleWithZone
>   http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:27765:16
>     PlatformRefhttp://localhost:8100/build/main.js:27747:16  
>   http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:96568:1   **webpack_require**
>   http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:20:12     
>   http://localhost:8100/build/main.js:66:18

I'm so confused, something must be wrongly initiated but the error stack does not really help...

Comment: Could you expand you example with folder structure, just so that we can verify you are importing the correct auth-data.ts file?

Answer (score 0):

```
this.authData.loginUser(this.loginForm.value.email, 
      this.loginForm.value.password)
```

Here you are accessing form parameters incorrectly.
The loginUser function expects 2 string arguments.

Try:

```
this.loginForm.controls["email"].value
this.loginForm.controls["password"].value
```

EDIT:
for the second error I am guessing this is the issue:

```
 resetPassword(email: string): any {
    return firebase.auth().sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
  }
```

I dont see firebase object set anywhere in the file.

Comment: I think that helped, thanks but now I have another error, let me update my initial post

Comment: isn't firebase imported via import { AngularFire } from 'angularfire2'; ? it seems like that, sublime does not throw me an error and the error I get is on the html side right ?

Comment: you have injected it as af..and used this.af.auth in the other functions

Answer (score 0):

> My guess would have been that 'this.authData' is never initiated, but even when I add this.authData = authData in the constructor, it does not change anything. (that also says that I don't understand how it gets initiated)

You do not need to do that as angular injector takes care of the initialization of the providers. You can read more about that [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html)

Regarding your issue, did you import and register your provider in the application root module, as stated in the tutorial?

Comment: I didnt think that was the issue here otherwise there would be a 'no provider for..' error